# How do I convert int? into int

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I've create a SPROC that saves an object and returns the id of the new object saved. Now, I'd like to return an int not an int?

```
public int Save(Contact contact)
{
  int? id;
  context.Save_And_SendBackID(contact.FirstName, contact.LastName, ref id);
  //How do I return an int instead of an int?
}
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
return id.Value; // If you are sure "id" will never be null
```

or

```
return id ?? 0; // Returns 0 if id is null
```

Comment: Note that `id.Value` will throw an exception when id is null.  In some contexts, that will be appropriate, otherwise, use `??`.

Comment: Does `??` only work with Nullable<>, or also regular reference types?

Comment: if works with all reference types. `x ?? y` is basically shorthand for `x!=null ? x : y`

Comment: Great, thanks.  I knew what it did, but just had that question pop in my mind.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the `GetValueOrDefault()` function on Nullable.

```
return id.GetValueOrDefault(0); // Or whatever default value is wise to use...
```

Note that this is similar to the [coalescing answer by Richard77](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040173/how-do-i-convert-int-into-int/3040186#3040186) but I would say slightly more readable...

However, deciding whether this is a good idea is up to you. Such that perhaps an exception is more appropriate?

```
if (! id.HasValue)
    throw new Exception("Value not found"); // TODO: Use better exception type!

return id.Value;
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting that throwing an exception might be the appropriate thing to do. It seems to me that too many programmers are very quick to using a default value, without first making sure that null isn't really an error.

Answer (score 3):

```
return id.Value;
```

You might wanna check if id.HasValue is true, and return 0 or something if not.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (id.HasValue) return id.Value;
else return 0;
```

Comment: or **return id??0**. Exactly the same :)

Comment: That's a rather long-winded way of saying "`id ?? 0`"

Comment: @Blogbeard:  Technically, it would be `return id ?? 0;` :)

Comment: @Philippe - actually, it isn't *quite* the same; the value as written checks *twice* whether a value is assigned. The `??` approach checks **once**. To check no times (and still behave 100% identically), you can use `return id.GetValueOrDefault()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
return id.HasValue ? id.Value : 0;
```

this returns the value of id in case it is not null and 0 in the other case.

Comment: What's wrong with `return id ?? 0;`, which does exactly the same thing and is more efficient?